# jQuery Event after changing class with toggleClass

Tags: jquery, class

I have a problem with jQuery and the toggleClass(). 
I want to create a div, which closes on clicking a button. The button changes and when I click again on this button the div will open again.

The problem is: When I click on the button the div closes and the class of the button changes - thats fine. But now when I click on the button with the new class - nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="contentclose"></div>
        <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".contentclose").click(
    function() {
        $(".content").animate({
            "height": "45px",
            "width": "45px",
            "padding": "0px"
        }, 1000);
        $(".content").children("p").animate({
            "opacity": "0"
        }, 1000);

        $(".contentclose").toggleClass("contentclose contentopen");

}
);

$(".contentopen").click(
    function() {
        $(".content").animate({
            "height": "400px",
            "width": "200px",
            "padding": "50px"
        }, 1000);
        $(".content").children("p").animate({
            "opacity": "1"
        }, 1000);

        $(".contentopen").toggleClass("contentopen contentclose");

}
); });
```

I hope you can help me...

Comment: Change `$(".contentclose").toggleClass` and `$(".contentopen").toggleClass` to `$(this).toggleClass` as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're binding your event handlers to the elements that have those classes *as of when your code doing the binding runs*. That code isn't magically re-run to rebind things later.

You can use *event delegation* to get something similar to that magic, though. Change:

```
$(".contentclose").click(function...
```

to

```
$(document).on("click", ".contentclose", function...
```

and change

```
$(".contentopen").click(function...
```

to

```
$(document).on("click", ".contentopen", function...
```

(Ideally, use a container that's closer to the buttons than `document`. Any common ancestor will do.)

What that does is bind `click` to the ancestor element (`document` in my example), but then trigger the relevant handler based on whether the click originated or passed through something matching the given selector when the event was bubbling.

So if a click reaches `document` having bubbled from (or through) a `.contentclose` button, the handler we've attached in that line is run. But if it bubbled from (or through) a `.contentclose` button, the other handler is run. It's dynamically determined when the click occurs, instead of being statically determined when you hook up the handler.

Comment: Oh man I never think about this ! I always call binding functions every time I change classes !

Comment: @RomainBraun: :-) Yeah, event delegation *fundamentally* changed how I hook up UIs once I finally fully internalized it a few years back.

Comment: and change `$(".contentclose").toggleClass` and `$(".contentopen").toggleClass` to `$(this).toggleClass` :)

Comment: @Omar: Probably, yeah, it's hard to tell what the intention is. But if the goal is just to change the one that was clicked, then yes, quite so.

Answer (score 0):

When the document is ready, the DOM do not contain a class with name contentopen, so it is impossible to bind the contentopen click event.