# Jquery hide unselected rows in a table that has been loaded in from a url.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

The important HTML

```
 <div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" id="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for User">
           <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" id="user_search" type="button"><i id="usersearchicon" class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </span>
 </div>
 <div id="user_results">
 </div>
```

The User result Html that is loaded

```
<table class="table" id="user_result_table">
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_content">
        <td>first_name1</td>
        <td>last_name1</td>
        <td>email1</td>
        <td style="display:none;" class="result_user_id">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_content">
        <td>first_name2</td>
        <td>last_name2</td>
        <td>email2</td>
        <td style="display:none;" class="result_user_id">2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#user_search").click(function(){
        var q = $("#q").val().split(/[ ,]+/).join(',');
        $("#user_results").load("{% url 'search' %}?q=" + q, function(){
            $(":not(.selected) #user_result_table tr.tr_content ").click(function(){
                $(this).toggleClass( "selected" );
                var selected_user = $(this).find(".result_user_id").html();
                $("#user_result_table tr.tr_content").not(".selected").hide();
                });
        });
     });
});

$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#usersearchicon").replaceWith("<i id='usersearchicon' class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>");
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $("#usersearchicon").replaceWith("<i id='usersearchicon' class='fa fa-search'></i>");
});
```

I want to load the user results from the query into the html and when the user selects a a row the other rows are hidden. This works but if I then select the result row that isn't hidden it disappears even though it now has a 'selected' class attributed to it. How do I stop the click from being registered if the row has a selected class attributed to it. I thought the selector :not(.selected) would have worked? Any Ideas. I thought i might have been something to do with this post [jQuery Event after changing class with toggleClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547361/jquery-event-after-changing-class-with-toggleclass) but couldn't get those suggestions to work on my code.

Comment: When the html returns from the load, do any of the rows already have the class of `.selected` ? Actually, are you able to show the html returned in the load

Comment: Yeah I can show the html on load. The answer is no though

Comment: I mean add the HTML that you load to the question above

Comment: Added it :) with generic placeholder for names and emails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding when the event is *binding*

Your code to append click handlers to the table rows that don't have the class `.selected` only ever runs once, and this is straight after the load. As you mentioned in comments if no table rows that are loaded have the class of selected then there is no point in that selector in this line:

```
$(":not(.selected) #user_result_table tr.tr_content ").click(function(){
```

as no rows when this runs (i.e. immediately after the load) have the class of selected.

Now the first time a row is clicked, all is good, it will hide all the other rows, and add a class to the row that was just clicked. If you click the row again, the same function is going to run, and the `.toggleClass` will then remove the `.selected` class and then since it no longer has a class of `.selected` it wil be hidden.

So if you want to ignore ones that have a class of '.selected' do it in the function i.e.:

```
//No point in the :not(.selected) here so removed)
 $("#user_result_table tr.tr_content ").click(function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) //If this doesn't have .selected
    {
         $(this).addClass( "selected" );
         var selected_user = $(this).find(".result_user_id").html();
         $("#user_result_table tr.tr_content").not(".selected").hide();
    }
 });
```

now it may be better to simply have a click handler that only runs once, so try jQuery [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/), this will means the click handler is only executed once i.e.

```
 $("#user_result_table tr.tr_content ").one('click',function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("selected");
     var selected_user = $(this).find(".result_user_id").html();
     $("#user_result_table tr.tr_content").not(".selected").hide();
 });
```

this may be closer to what you are after perhaps?

The article you have linked to is about event delegation, and the principle is similar to the issue you are having. The key is when the event binding happens. Your approach is not exactly the same as you are binding your event to a class that never changes (`.tr_content`) meaning you are not removing that class. Your handler is running for all `.tr_content` when they are clicked, regardless if they have any other classes (i.e. regardless if they have `.selected` or not). In the article he has two click handlers the first one is for elements that are on the page when the code runs, but the second is for elements that are not on the page when the code runs. In order to do this, you must delegate the event to an element that is on the page (i.e. a parent of the element, that is on the page when the code runs). The ultimate parent is the document of course as per the answer.